# What is the best methodology in mounting customizables to a 3d avatar in Unity?

Tags: 3d, unity, methodology

Someone I know suggested just making every customizable on the model then just hide the non active ones. But that doesn't sound very efficient for me.

So my question is what is the best method to use for making customizable 3d avatars in general? And specifically what would be best used in Unity3d?

Answer (score 2):

Another programmer friend gave me this which I think is also an answer to the question

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/16485-quot-stitch-multiple-body-parts-into-one-character-quot

Answer (score 1):

How exactly to make a 3D avatar customizable depends on the exact customizations desired (eg. change color? change clothing? change gender?) For example, changing color could mean swapping the texture used in the model's material. However the question about mounting objects is pretty straightforward...

If the character has a skeleton (and if this is an animated player model, it has a skeleton for the animation) then simply hierarchy link customization objects to specific bones in the character's skeleton. You can easily assign a parent to an object in code.